# How to solve HashMissing using pip in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

While trying to install `pip`, `virtualenv` the following error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
      File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
        from pip import main 
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
        from pip.commands import commands, get_summaries, get_similar_commands
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from pip.commands.bundle import BundleCommand  
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/bundle.py", line 6, in <module>
        from pip.commands.install import InstallCommand   
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 5, in <module>
        from pip.req import InstallRequirement, RequirementSet, parse_requirements   
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .req_install import InstallRequirement  
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 42, in <module>
        from pip.utils.hashes import Hashes   
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 5, in <module>
        from pip.exceptions import HashMismatch, HashMissing, InstallationError
    ImportError: cannot import name HashMissing
```

How can I solve the `Hashmissing` error? Tried through [HTTPSHandler link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581999/pip-raises-importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. In my case it was after a system upgrade and “repairing” a `virtualenv` according to https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2012/05/30/fixing-virtualenv-after-upgrading-your-distributionpython/, ie. running `virtualenv` over it again. As I see it now, this merges two versions of `pip` and `setuptools` by overwriting some files and creating a broken mess. My solution is to remove `pip` and `setuptools` manually from `virtualenv`’s `site-packages` and then running `virtualenv` to repair.

```
VENV_DIR="<your venv dir>"
rm -r "$VENV_DIR"/lib/python2.7/site-packages/{pip,setuptools} "$VENV_DIR"/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-* "$VENV_DIR"/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-*
virtualenv "$VENV_DIR"
source "$VENV_DIR"/bin/activate
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

In your case it is not `virtualenv`, but I think the cause is similar (two `pip` versions one over the other).

Answer (score 0):

Answer below is good, with one fix - must use pip2:

```
VENV_DIR="<your venv dir>"
rm -r "$VENV_DIR"/lib/python2.7/site-packages/{pip,setuptools} "$VENV_DIR"/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-* "$VENV_DIR"/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-*
virtualenv "$VENV_DIR"
source "$VENV_DIR"/bin/activate
pip2 install -U pip setuptools
```

Answer (score -3):

No such class 'HashMissing' in Python 2.7 so you get this error.

Why not just `import pip.exceptions` 'as is'?

Comment: It's was not clear from the original post (my edit is still pending), but the import happens in code that is not under the users control, so they cannot simple change the import line.